# DocuSign Envelopes: listStatus "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make a API call to the eSignature REST API Envelopes: listStatus (as shown [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatus/))

However, I get ERROR 400 Bad Request and the following:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}
```

Even trying it in DocuSign's API explorer I get the same error. The error seems to be pointing to a issue with how the request body is formed. DocuSign suggests this,

```
{
  "envelopeIds": [
    "44c5ad6c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ebda5e2dfe15",
    "8e26040d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1e29b924d237",
    "c8b40a2d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4fe56fe10f95"
  ]
}
```

however, if I use **"envelopeIds"** in the body instead I get:

```
{
       "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
       "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime, or 'envelope_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified."
}
```

replacing "**envelopeIds**" with "**envelope_ids**" I get:

Response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}
```

and even using a **comma separated list** like, I get the same error:

Body:

```
{ "envelopeIds": "44c5ad6c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ebda5e2dfe15,8e26040d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1e29b924d237"}
```

Response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried this using both postman and DocuSign's API explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `?envelope_ids=request_body` in the URL.
Then it should work with the body:

```
{
  "envelopeIds": [
    "44c5ad6c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ebda5e2dfe15",
    "8e26040d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1e29b924d237",
    "c8b40a2d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4fe56fe10f95"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using their PHP SDK, here is the code :

```php
    //Get envelopes API
    $envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi($this->docusignClient);
    //Create ListStatusOptions object for the listStatus endpoint
    $lso = new EnvelopesApi\ListStatusOptions();
    //Important : Specify that the envelope ids will be in the request body
    $lso->setEnvelopeIds('request_body');
    //Call list status
    $envelopesInformation = $envelopesApi->listStatus(
        account_id:$this->accountId,
        //The request body, as a new EnvelopeIdsRequest object, whith the values as an array of strings
        envelope_ids_request: new EnvelopeIdsRequest(['envelope_ids'=>$toCheck]),
        //The carefuly crafted ListStatusOptions object
        options: $lso);
```

As found in @JD Brennan 's answer, you must specify that you'll send your ids in the request body, and it is done with a ListStatusOption object.